# combining array of hashes based on specific key

Tags: ruby, hash

I need a group an array of hashes based on a particular key of each hash. For example, take this:

```
[
    [0] {
        :status => "pending",
             :x => 1,
             :y => 2
    },
    [1] {
        :status => "pending",
             :x => 33,
             :y => 74
    },
    [2] {
        :status => "done",
             :x => 33,
             :y => 74
    }
]
```

I need to convert it to this:

```
{
    "pending" => [
        [0] {
            :status => "pending",
                 :x => 1,
                 :y => 2
        },
        [1] {
            :status => "pending",
                 :x => 33,
                 :y => 74
        }
    ],
       "done" => [
        [0] {
            :status => "done",
                 :x => 33,
                 :y => 74
        }
    ]
}
```

I am grouping the array by :status key. I have done this (it works):

```
a.inject({}) {|a, b| (a[b[:status]] ||= []) << b; a }
```

But, is there a simpler, less cryptic one-liner that can do the same thing?

Comment: Doesn't your way work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use [`group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)? It does exactly what you need.

```
a.group_by {|b| b[:status] }
```

Comment: always think of `group_by` before you `inject` `each_with_object`, i'd say :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not a common enough operation to warrant a built-in descriptive method, but I would tweak your line slightly.

Instead of using `#inject()`, how about using [`#each_with_object()`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object)? It's more appropriate for passing the same object over an iteration, as that's exactly what it does - it's also more descriptive than "inject", IMO.

That has the added benefit of removing the `; a` from the end of the block: this is the problem with using inject to pass the same object between each iteration. Therefore, the final line becomes (with some variable name tweaking):

```
ary.each_with_object({}) {|e, obj| (obj[e[:status]] ||= []) << e }
```

The return value of each_with_object is the hash that's being built up, so you can assign the above to a variable, or return it from your method.

In the end, if you want it to be more descriptive in your application, wrap that line in a method that *is* descriptive:

```
def index_with_status(ary)
    ary.each_with_object({}) {|e, obj| (obj[e[:status]] ||= []) << e }
end
```